# How to extract particular data from 800+ downloaded HTML files en masse

Tags: html, excel

I've downloaded around 800 pages off a clients website. There are three pieces of information I want to get off these pages and list them all in a single Excel document. Is this possible?

The data I need to get from each page is (I have included a bit of info regarding where the code is on the clients website):

Garage Name (This is the pages meta title)

`<html class="__ff">
<head>
<title>Garage Name Here</title>`

Garage Phone Number (this is located with a div)

`<div class="box_area_body">
<p class="dealer_number">
<a href="tel: phone number">phone number</a>`

Number of Cars

`<span data-bind="text: $root.SearchData.Pagination.TotalRecords()">number of cars here</span>`

Is this possible? It's worth knowing my knowledge is limited when it comes to things like this!

Comment: This task is more suited for some other scripting languages. Any of the following could help you: Python (with Scrapy), PowerShell or many of the UNIX world (Grep, Awk, ...). It is possible in Excel but you should use a hammer for a nail, not a screwdriver.

Comment: @xificurC Can you explain?

Comment: @xificurC don't forget ruby as well :)

Comment: @SDemeda - every language has its use, VBA is fine for manipulating Excel but not really suited for scraping data from html pages. Many scripting languages provide great tools to extract the data, e.g. Python's Scrapy library loads your html as a tree and you can simply tell it to extract e.g. all `a`s which have a parent `div` of class `box_area_body`. These languages also carry more tools to manipulate strings. Overall the code would be shorter and simpler in other languages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using Scrapy with Python. If that doesn't work, I'll try using the answer @user3514930 provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use somethink like that:

```
Dim FName As String
Dim Str, Tmp As String
Dim i, e As Long

i = 1
Range("A1:D6").Clear
FName = Dir("e:\0\*.htm*")
Do While FName <> ""
    Open "e:\0\" & FName For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, Str
            e = InStr(1, Str, "<title>", vbTextCompare)
            If (e > 0) Then
                Tmp = Mid(Str, e + 7, InStr(1, Str, "</title>", vbTextCompare) - e - 7)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = FName
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = Tmp
            End If
            e = InStr(1, Str, "phone number"">", vbTextCompare)
            If (e > 0) Then
                Tmp = Mid(Str, e + 14, InStr(1, Str, "</a>", vbTextCompare) - e - 14)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = Tmp
            End If
            e = InStr(1, Str, ".TotalRecords()"">", vbTextCompare)
            If (e > 0) Then
                Tmp = Mid(Str, e + 17, InStr(1, Str, "</span>", vbTextCompare) - e - 17)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = Tmp
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Close #1
    FName = Dir
Loop
```

The Sub read all the files Htm or Html in a dir, extract (in base or the format) the data and put in the active sheet...